# Save radioGroup value into MYSQL using android

Tags: android, mysql

I'm new in android developing and I know this question has asked already but I couldn't find any way to solve my problem.

I've done all my approaches as all value of text fields are storing in DB But I have some problem with inserting the selected radio button value into the database.

Here is php file.

```php
    <?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    require 'init.php';

    $addtittle = $_POST['ad_title'];

    $addprice = $_POST['ad_price'];

    $condition = $_POST['ad_condition'];

    $km = $_POST['mileage'];

    $horsepower = $_POST['horse_power'];

    $vinnumber = $_POST['vin_no'];

    $fuel = $_POST['fuel_type'];

    $transition = $_POST['transition'];

    $transaction = $_POST['transaction_type'];

    $description = $_POST['ad_desc'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `ad_detail`(`ad_title`, `ad_price`, `ad_condition`, `mileage`, `horse_power`, `vin_no`, `fuel_type`, `transition`, `transaction_type`, `ad_desc`) 
    VALUES ('".$addtittle."','".$addprice."', '".$condition."', '".$km."', '".$horsepower."','".$vinnumber."', '".$fuel."', '".$transition."', '".$transaction."', '".$description."')";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

        echo("Data Post Successfully");

    }else{

        echo("No");
    }

}
```

Here is java code

```java
    if (et_title.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Tittle not be Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (et_price.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Price not be Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (et_horse_power.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Horse Power not be Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (et_mileage.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Mileage not be Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (et_description.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Description not be Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (et_vin.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Vin No. not be Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    String str_title = et_title.getText().toString().trim();
                    int str_cc = Integer.parseInt(et_horse_power.getText().toString().trim());
                    String str_vin = et_vin.getText().toString().trim();
                    int str_price = Integer.parseInt(et_price.getText().toString().trim());
                    String str_desc = et_description.getText().toString().trim();
                    int mileage = Integer.parseInt(et_mileage.getText().toString().trim());

                    StringRequest
                            request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            Toast.makeText(SellerActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            Toast.makeText(SellerActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }) {

                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                            params.put("ad_title", str_title);
                            params.put("ad_price", String.valueOf(str_price));
                            params.put("horse_power", String.valueOf(str_cc));
                            params.put("mileage", String.valueOf(mileage));
                            params.put("vin_no", str_vin);
                            params.put("ad_desc", str_desc);
                            return params;
                        }
                    };

                    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SellerActivity.this);
                    requestQueue.add(request);
                }
```

Here is XML of RadioGroup

```xml
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/background"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    app:cardElevation="3dp">

                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/radio_group_used"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@color/switchblue"
                        android:checkedButton="@+id/radio_btn_new"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radio_btn_new"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_4sdp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_4sdp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/switch_off2"
                            android:button="@null"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="New"
                            android:onClick="radioCheckButtonUsed"
                            android:textColor="@drawable/switch_text2" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radio_btn_used"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_4sdp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_4sdp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/switch_on2"
                            android:button="@null"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Used"
                            android:onClick="radioCheckButtonUsed"
                            android:textColor="@drawable/switch_text2" />
                    </RadioGroup>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
            textViewChoice.setText("You Selected " + rb.getText());
            //You can do whatever you want with that rb (the selected one)
        }
    });
```

Comment: i couldn't understand it can you please give a proper code so that i can insert the selected radio button value into the database.

Comment: You need to first declare your RadioGroup: 
`RadioGroup radioGroup = findViewById<>(R.id.radio_group_used);`

Then you do:

```radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
            --! HERE INSIDE "rb.getText();" you have your value that has to be added! I don't know exaclty how you add it: db.add(rb.getText(););

        }
    });
```